# My ISO Downloaded as Tar.Gz?

Tags: tar

I was downloading a Linux-based operating system but instead of ISO, it came as tar.gz (OEM.tar.gz, I think but maybe not). How do I burn this OS to a flash drive?

Comment: Need some more details as a tar file could contain anything. What distro is it? What's in the tar file? `tar -tvzf OEM.tar.gz`. There will probably be one big file in there which is the disk image that needs to be `dd`d to your flash drive.

Comment: CypressOS. When I extract, CypressOS.x86_64-0.0.1.raw displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look inside the tar file:

```
tar ztvf OEM.tar.gz
```

Maybe "they" have put the ISO and some READMEs in that archive.

If so, extract the whole archive by typing:

```
tar zxf OEM.tar.gz
```

I think there will be some README file with instructions about how to burn or how to put it on a pendrive...

Comment: I right click to extract, and it says "CypressOS.x86_64-0.0.1.raw" -- does this mean it's still extracting? When it extracts the progress autohides.

Comment: I don't know about clicking... I'm from the typing species... I just can guess that when the window of the extracting program closes, the extraction job is done and you should have "CypressOS.x86_64-0.0.1.raw" somewhere... look for text files with instructions side by side to this file.

Comment: Exactly. I do have CypressOS.x86_64-0.0.1.raw, but how do I burn that to a flash drive?

Comment: When the flashdrive is /dev/sde, `cat CypressOS.x86_64-0.0.1.raw > /dev/sde` should do the job. Triple check the device name or you might overwrite the beginning of your harddisk.

Comment: https://susestudio.com/a/taKOBj/cypressos has a link with install instructions left to the download button:   https://susestudio.com/help/use/disk-image.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't see why there are so many instructions as to how to burn it... So in terminal I type exactly the following and it'll boot from USB? cat CypressOS.x86_64-0.0.1.raw > /dev/sde

Comment: Is your USB stick really /dev/sde?